# Ajax call return json to model I can use data from in my own function

Tags: ajax, backbone.js

New to Backbone, so I may be over/under complicating things. (built spa's with my own functions in the past)

Psudo code of what I used to do:

```
AjaxCall(
  url: "get json result"
  success: 
     parse json
     call Update(json.a, json.b)
)

function Update(a, b){
    //do something with a/b var's
}
```

For a more abstract idea of what I am envisioning atm. If I click an update button, I want it to hit the server and return a success/fail status along with an Id and a message (imagining all in json format).

Found a few examples, but none seem to fit so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do that, you'd use a Backbone model:

```
var Message = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: "messages"
});

var myMessage = new Message();
myMessage.save({}, {
    success: function(model, response, options){
        // code...
    },
    error: function(model, xhr, options){
        // code...
    }
});
```

Basically: the model configures the API call, and `save` will use backbone's sync layer to handle the actual AJAX. You can pass `success` and `error` callbacks to the `save function.

The first parameter to the save function are the attributes which are to be saved (see http://backbonejs.org/#Model-save), which seem to need to be empty according to your question.

Since the model instance has no `id` attribute, the save call will trigger a POST request to the API. If by any chance you actually need to provide an `id` (so that a PUT call gets triggered instead), simply do

```
myMessage.save({id: 15}, {
    success: function(model, response, options){
        // code...
    },
    error: function(model, xhr, options){
        // code...
    }
});
```